# Pattern that is not a negative integer

Tags: bash, regex

In bash, I can use Posix Character Class such as

```
digit="[[:digit:]]"
```

There are also

```
[[:alnum:]], [[:alpha:]], [[:ascii:]], [[:punct:]]
```

What pattern can I use to match something that starts with - but is not a negative integer?

I cannot use the negated class `[^[:digit:]]`, a character that is not a digit, because
`-2345dsfg2546` is not a negative integer.

Comment: Correct, I want to construct a regex using character classes.  I am writing a bash function that allows parsing option with multiple parameters.  I want to detect whether the next argument might represents an option.  The first character has to be a `-`, but do not want to exclude negative numbers.

Comment: Why are you doing this, when Bash already has a built-in function for this? `while getopts ...`

Comment: It has but not for what I want to do.  getopts need to evolve because of its archaic nature.

Comment: This question is a perfect example for an [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: How is it an XY-Problem, so I can change the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first character is a hyphen and the rest of the string contains a non-digit:

```bash
if [[ $str == -* && ${str:1} == *[^[:digit:]]* ]]; then
  echo "str is not a negative integer
fi
```

Simpler

```bash
if [[ $str == -*[^[:digit:]]* ]]; then
```

As a regex

```bash
if [[ $str ~= ^-.*[^[:digit:]] ]]
```